# Adding 0 or null to missing fields

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

student(sid, sname)

teacher(tid, tname)

enrollment(sid, cid, tid)

course(cid, course)

rank(sid, tid, grade, date, valid)

I need to calculate the average grade of all the teachers (data is in rank table), when only the grade from the most recent date counts (and if it's invalid - ignore it).

I wrote the following query, and it's working nice. The problem is that I also need the average for ALL the teachers, including those who were not ranked yet/their rank is invalid (their average grade will be 0 in that case, and I'll have to count their students like I did for the others).
I think it's something with LEFT OUTER JOIN, but all the examples I see online have only two tables in FROM, and I can't figure out the right syntax in my case.

```
SELECT teacher.tid, 
       tname, 
       AVG(grade) AS avgGrade, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT enrollment.sid) AS studCount 
FROM rank, 
     teacher, 
     enrollment, 
     (   SELECT rank.sid, rank.tid, MAX(date) AS maxDate 
         FROM rank       
         GROUP BY sid, tid
     ) lastGrades 
WHERE teacher.tid=enrollment.tid 
  AND rank.tid=teacher.tid 
  AND rank.tid=lastGrades.tid 
  AND rank.sid=lastGrades.sid 
  AND rank.date=lastGrades.maxDate 
  AND valid = TRUE 
GROUP BY teacher.tid, tname
```

Comment: I dont know if postgres has a COLAESCE.

Comment: @Mihai, PostgreSQL **has** a COALESCE function, check this link: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL

Comment: Do it with JOINS but use a LEFT JOIN for teachers so you get all teachers.

Comment: True, PostgreSQL does support COALESCE. Maybe I should try a different approach and use some form of UNION instead of LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a subquer to look up the latest rank per `(teacher, student)` combination.  Use a `left join` to count enrollments that have not been ranked:

```
select  t.tid
,       t.tname
,       avg(r.grade) as AverageRank
,       count(distinct e.sid) as StudentCount
from    teacher t
join    enrollment e
on      t.tid = e.tid
left join
        rank r
on      r.tid = t.tid
        and r.sid = e.sid
        and r.valid = true
        and r.date =
        (
        select  max(date)
        from    rank r2
        where   r2.sid = r.sid
                and r2.tid = r.tid
                and r2.valid = true
        )
group by
        t.tid
,       t.tname
```

[Example without data at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bfe16/4/0)

The table design is kind of strange.  You'd expect a student to enroll in a course, not in a teacher!

Comment: I wasn't able to try it, there's a syntax error somewhere. But I'm not familiar with "over" and "partition", hence not supposed to use them :)

Comment: @Augustina: Updated the answer without `row_number()`.  This one works on SQL Fiddle, so hopefully no syntax errors.